# get mouse position from javascript mouse scroll event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the mouse position on mousescroll. I'm also trying to make this compatible with all browsers. So far I have the following javascript which listens for the mouse scroll event:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', mouseScroll, false);
function mouseScroll(){
  alert( /* mouse position code here */ );
}
```

But I'm not sure how to pass the event into the function to then use something like `e.pageX` and also I'm not sure what event property to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', mouseScroll, false);

function mouseScroll(e){

   // e.clientX or e.pageX is available here.

}
```

Comment: Ah that was more simple than I thought. Although is this fully browser compatible? I read somewhere about using DOMMouseScroll and mousewheel too? What is the most full proof method?

Comment: Here is a link that should help you ... http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/

Answer (score 3):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/sFJ4r/

**JS:-**

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', mouseScroll, false);

function mouseScroll(e) {
    console.log(window.scrollY);
}
```

`DOMMouseScroll` is not supported on all browser set except `Firefox`. <kbd>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMMouseScroll</kbd>

[image]

### Also, if you are targeting all browsers you can use http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/sFJ4r/1/

```
window.onmousewheel=document.onmousewheel=mouseScroll;

if(document.addEventListener){
      document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',mouseScroll,false);
 }

function mouseScroll(e) {
    console.log(e.pageY);
}
```